# python update mysql tables with foreign keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm trying to call a mysql stored procedure. I need to add parameters from a csv file as well as a dictionary column queried from the DB. In my db server_id is the foreign key for guardpoints table. When i try to add the serverid as a paremeter i get the below assertion error. I'm not sure if the py file can tell i have the serverid defined in the serverdict function.

```
#create dictionary with server_id foreign key
import mysql.connector
# create database connection

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='xx', user='xx', password='xx', db='xx')


# cursor = conn.cursor()

def serverdict():
    cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)

    cursor.execute("select server_id, name from servers")

    for serverid in cursor:
        print("* {server_id}: {name}".format(**serverid))
```

---

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
from serverdict import serverdict
# open csv file


with open('DBstatus.csv') as dbcsvfile:
    dbstatus = csv.DictReader(dbcsvfile)
    for row in dbstatus:
        print(row['Report Id'], row['Status Id'], row['Host Name'], row["OS Type"], row['Host Description'], row['License Type'],
              row['One-Way Enabled'], row['FS Agent Registration Status'], row['FS Agent Version'], row['Host Name'], row['Last Policy Update'],
              row['Guard Point Id'], row['Guard Path'], row['Policy Id'], row['Policy Name'], row['Guard Enabled'],
              row['Guard Point Status'], row['Error Reason'])

        serverdict()

        #create database connection

        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='xxxx', user='xxx', password='xxx', db='xxx')

        cursor = conn.cursor()


        #Create parameters for stored procedure
        guardpointparams = (row['FS Agent Registration Status'], row['FS Agent Version'], row['Guard Path'], serverid['server_id'])

        #call stored procedure
        updateguardpointstable = cursor.callproc('update_guardpoints', guardpointparams)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Update Guardpoints Table.py", line 29, in 
    guardpointparams = (row['FS Agent Registration Status'], row['FS Agent Version'], row['Guard Path'], serverid['server_id'])
NameError: name 'serverid' is not defined

Comment: In all of your other dictionary references, you use `row[key]` where row is defined because you're iterating through the CSV (`for row in dbstatus`). However, `serverid['server_id']` will not work because there is no dictionary named `serverid`. Maybe this is just a typo? Or are you trying to accessing something not in the CSV?

Comment: serverid is not from the csv. It is coming directly from the database table. i tried to create a dictionary in the first set of code and named the function serverdict(). Thinking i could add that to the 2nd file and pass in the serverid parameter.

Comment: OK -- so, it looks like you're just running that function but not actually assigning its return value to anything. You'll need to assign the return value of that function like `s_dict = serverdict()`. I'm guessing that it returns a dictionary, so then you'd access it like `print(s_dict['serverid'])`. I'm just being general though, since I'm not 100% on how your code is supposed to be working.